# Life with empty about:plugins (so without flash)

Tags: adobe-flash

I use Firefox as it is stated in the $subject. Nevertheless there are still too many contents (I'm talking about mostly videos) on the web that needs flash. This is what I use for it:

- https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/
- https://userscripts.org/scripts/show/87011

So in this way I can download/view with VLC ex.: youtube videos. But aren't there a better way to do this? To get the life without flash easier?

And no, enabling html5 on youtube... doesn't help, because it looks like very-very-very low percentage of the youtube videos are viewable in html5..

UPDATE: so I don't want to run videos inside my browser. They will be always slower compared to a video natively played in ex.: VLC. Also AFAIK it's much safer to have empty about:plugins and play the needed videos in VLC.

Comment: I use a script (which uses cclive in the background) I mapped to `v` (for view) and it opens the current video or the URL the mouse hovers over in a VLC instance. That's as simple as it can get. However, this work only for videos from popular movie sites, it does not replace the flash plugin.

Comment: I have Flash plugin installed but blocked by [Flashblock](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flashblock/). In the rare case I want to see the Flash content I just click the icon placed by the addon in the area reserved for the plugin. Of course, there are cases when this fails (either the blocking or the playing on demand), but are fairly rare.

Comment: Well, life without flash is easy if you don't visit or want to view any of the video hosting sites. Then again, I don't like watching video in a web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Life without the adobe flash plugin is not going to be easy until there are usable and free alternative flash players.

Here is a list of alternatives: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash#Alternatives

IMHO the most promising of those is [shumway](https://blog.mozilla.org/research/2012/11/12/introducing-the-shumway-open-swf-runtime-project/).

Comment: ...which has now made its way into Firefox Nightlies!! Check them out.